# Google Search Appliance: Need to understand how sorting works

Tags: sorting, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I want to understand how sorting works in GSA in below situations:

1) I am executing the query "Jayesh Bhoyar Autobiography" and I received 2000 records and in the query I have also mentioned sort by Date. So my understanding is GSA will pick Top 1000 records from above list based on the Relevance and then Sort it by Date?

However I want GSA should return only top 100 results for "Jayesh Bhoyar Autobiography" as per the relevance and sort on those top 100 records based on the Date. IS this possible?

If yes, how it is possible?

Regards,

Jayesh Bhoyar

Answer (score 1):

The GSA can't do this by itself. If you want to do this, you can easily build a simple application that fetches the first hundred results sorted by relevance, then sorts those results by date. Use the simple XML API to fetch unformatted results from the GSA.

[Search Protocol Reference](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/)

Comment: Thanks Dave , I will try to implement as per your suggestion.